# How do I add multiple attachments depending of the user and their files to attach?

Tags: python, pandas, smtplib

How can I send multiple attachments to one email given this dataframe? I have only managed to send one file per mail, but I would like to attach several files in the same mail for one recipient.

My dataframe looks like: [image: Dataframe]

My code where I send the email:

```
def enviar_mail(from, to, file_name, link, title):

  from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
  from email.mime.text import MIMEText
  from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
  import smtplib
  from email import encoders
  from google.colab import files
  from email.utils import formataddr
  import email.utils
  import time
  from datetime import date

  msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
  msg['From'] =email.utils.formataddr(( "Mail",from))
  msg['To'] = to
  msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'

  bodytext=f"BODY OF THE EMAIL IN HTML"
  body=f"""\
          <html>
              <body>
                <p style="color:black;"> {bodytext}
                </p>
              </body>
          </html>
"""


  msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

  attachment = open(file_name, 'rb')
  part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
  part.set_payload((attachment).read())
  encoders.encode_base64(part)
  part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file_name)
  msg.attach(part)
  
  mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com',587)
  mailserver.ehlo()
  mailserver.starttls()
  mailserver.login(from, 'mypassword')

  mailserver.send_message(msg, rcpt_options=['NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE'])
  mailserver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach multiple attachments as several parts:

```py
attachment1 = open(file_1, 'rb')
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(attachment1.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file_1)
msg.attach(part)


attachment2 = open(file_2, 'rb')
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(attachment2.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file_2)
msg.attach(part)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but that would not work  in my case because it would depend on how many files one user could have. For example, one can have 2 files but other can have other number. The thing here is to loop over the dataframe with .loc[email] but I do not know how to make it work